# Sign a PNG file to obtain a CMS signature as a result

Tags: rust, openssl

I am very new to Rust and am attempting to sign a PNG file to obtain a CMS signature as a result.

I'm using cargo openssl version  `"0.10.62"`

```
use openssl::cms::{CmsContentInfo, CMSOptions};

use openssl::pkey::PKey;
use openssl::x509::X509;
use std::fs::{self};


fn main() {
    let certificate_contents = fs::read("files/certificate.pem").unwrap();
    let private_key_contents = fs::read("files/private_key.pem").unwrap();
    let image_contents = fs::read("files/image.png").unwrap();

    let signcert = X509::from_pem(&certificate_contents).unwrap();
    let pkey = PKey::private_key_from_pem(&private_key_contents).unwrap();
    
    let flags = CMSOptions::DETACHED;

    
    let cms = CmsContentInfo::sign(
      Some(&signcert),
      Some(&pkey),
      None, 
      Some(&image_contents),
      flags
    ).unwrap();


    fs::write("files/signature.pem", cms.to_pem().unwrap()).unwrap();
}
```

However, I'm encountering an issue. The file signature.pem is generated, but it does not pass the terminal verification with the following command:

```
openssl cms -verify -in signature.pem -inform PEM -content image.png -CAfile certificate.pem -out verified_content -noverify
```

to generate the signature.pem in terminal I use:

```
openssl cms -sign -in image.png -signer certificate.pem -inkey private_key.pem -outform PEM -out signature.pem -nodetach
```

terminal openssl version: `OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023)`

Comment: Fullcode with pems and image example https://github.com/kherel/sign_rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag and the way of checking was wrong

right code:

```
    let flags = CMSOptions::BINARY | CMSOptions::DETACHED;
```

the way to verify the pem in terminal

```
openssl cms -verify -in signature.pem -inform PEM -content image.png -CAfile certificate.pem -out verified_image.png -noverify -binary
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you changed so we don't have to diff the questions & answers code & openssl invocation.